# How to fix my combat script when no errors are showing?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have created this script in hopes of creating a combat system that can play multiple animations in one button; however, when I put them in the light attack section of the script, the animations will not play, yet I have no errors in my code.

I have tried reorganizing, using the actual animation ids, changing variable names, etc.

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = script.Parent
local Humanoid = Character.Humanoid
AnimationId1 = "rbxassetid://2046787868"
AnimationId2 = "rbxassetid://2046881922"
AnimationId3 = "rbxassetid://"
AnimationId4 = "rbxassetid://2048242167"
Debounce = true
local Key = 'U'
local Key2 = 'I'
local Key3 = 'O'
local Key4 = 'P'

local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

--Animation for the Light attk combo sequence.
UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(Input, IsTyping)
    for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        if Input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode[Key] then
            local Animation = Instance.new("Animation")
            Animation.AnimationId = AnimationId1, AnimationId2
            local LoadAnimation = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
            if v == 1 then
                LoadAnimation:Play(AnimationId1)
            elseif v == 2 then
                LoadAnimation:Play(AnimationId2)
            end
        end
    end
end)



--Animation for the Blocking sequence.
UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(Input, IsTyping)
    if IsTyping then return end
    if Input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode[Key4] and Debounce then
        Debounce = false
        local Animation = Instance.new("Animation")
        Animation.AnimationId = AnimationId4
        local LoadAnimation = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
        LoadAnimation:Play()
        wait(.5)
        LoadAnimation:Stop()
        Debounce = true
    end
end)
```

The blocking part of this script works perfectly, however, when I try to use the light attack section, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say, the light attack doesn't work, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: When I press the button ("U"), none of the animations play. But I get no errors. It just wont play anything, so nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried printing the values for your if statement, or printing on the first line of the if statement like `U pushed. Playing animations`, these are usually my first steps in TS code that doesn't work as intended but compiles/runs.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It works until "if v == 1 then". There seems to be some sort of disconnect

Comment: is it possible your value `v` is `"1"` and not `1`? you can check this by doing `type(v)` and see if you get `number` or `string`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Where exactly in the function would I put that?

Comment: right before `if v == 1 then` you can put `print(v, type(v))` this should then print `1 number` or `1 string`assuming the value of v is 1

Comment: It only says that it is userdata

Comment: I am no overly familiar with roblox, but based on the documentation `GetChildren()` is going to return an object that i believe has a name, you can try `v.name` in the print. It is also possible you want to use your `i` value and not the `v`. other then that i am unsure what to do next

Comment: All I get is that it's userdata, so I can't move past this because of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your light attack function, `v` is a [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/Player) object. So any check like `v == 1` or `v == 2` will fail because it is the wrong type. It also doesn't really make sense that you would iterate over all of the players when they press the 'U' button.

You can make it play an animation just like you did with your blocking animation code.

```
-- make a counter to help decide which animation to play
local swingCount = 0
local currentSwingAnimation    

--Animation for the Light attack combo sequence.
UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(Input, IsTyping)
    if IsTyping then return end

    if Input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode[Key] then
        swingCount = swingCount + 1

        -- cancel any animation currently playing
        if currentSwingAnimation then
            currentSwingAnimation:Stop()
            currentSwingAnimation = nil
        end

        if swingCount == 1 then
            -- play the first animation
            local Animation = Instance.new("Animation")
            Animation.AnimationId = AnimationId1
            currentSwingAnimation = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
            currentSwingAnimation.Looped = false
            currentSwingAnimation:Play()

        elseif swingCount == 2 then
            -- play the second swing animation
            local Animation = Instance.new("Animation")
            Animation.AnimationId = AnimationId2
            currentSwingAnimation = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
            currentSwingAnimation.Looped = false
            currentSwingAnimation:Play()

            -- reset the swing counter to start the combo over
            swingCount = 0
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped out a lot! But it seems to run into another problem where it loops the 2nd animation and doesn't stop until you spam "U", and then wont play again.